# Angular e2e testing without chromedriver

Tags: windows, angular, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I am working on angular application e2e tests in very closed and secure environment, where it is not allowed to install chromedriver. It is Windows 7 with IE11 installed.

Command:

```
npm install chromedriver --save-dev
```

results with:

```
> chromedriver@2.31.0 install C:\_LocalWorkspace\Projects\SomeProject\node_modules\chromedriver
> node install.js

Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/chromedriver_win32.zip
Saving to C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32.zip
ChromeDriver installation failed Error with http request: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.21.208:443
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN app@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
```

What are my options for e2e tests in this circumstances?

**EDIT1:**

The problem can be described in other words. The environment that I am working in is closed for direct binary downloading. I am working for a client that has such policy and I can not do anything about that. I am also not allowed to install chrome browser so I have to use internet explorer. Therefore, only available webdrivr is iedriver. ( Please correct me if I am wrong )

My main problem is to install all requirements to make protractor works. It is like I have no Internet connection, but just for binaries. Most of the npm dependencies can be installed normally.

Like:

`npm instal webdriver-manager` which works,

but

`node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` fails to download these three files:

- https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/chromedriver_win32.zip
- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.11.1/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64.zip

I have an option (from the client) to download files in isolated environment let them through security check and then use them. I did that and I have placed those 3 files in `SomeProject\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium` directory.

Then I have tried to run node `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` again, hoping that it will skip the download and continue with the normal process steps, extracting etc. But it did not, again it failed to download with the same message.

Then I have extracted the zip files manually.

At this point I am not sure, does `node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` need to do more things than downloading and extracting. Because it has terminated on download, and I did it manually but how can I know what it would do after if the download was successful?

Anyway, I tried `npm run e2e` command (which is starting my protractor tests) with extracted binaries in place.

The result was: 
    [13:24:07] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
    [13:24:07] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    [13:24:11] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://53.150.192.128:58001/wd/hub
    [13:24:11] E/launcher - The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://sel
    enium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

From error message it is clear that I should download the latest version of iedriver from [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) as it is described [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

I have chosen the latest version, currently 3.4

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.4/

that looks like this:

[image]

I took the first link IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0.zip downloaded it and extract it in `SomeProject\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`

But the problem with the same error message still exists. Am I placing it in correct target directory? Should I download maybe some other file from the image?

Please advise how can I install iedriever and run protractor tests.

**EDIT2:**

Also, the problem can be generalized and put like. How to install protractor dependencies by downloading them manually?

Comment: The obvious options are other drivers, i.e. iedriver. It's not clear why you didn't try to solve the original problem in the first place. It isn't clear where 'does not allow' conclusion comes from.

Comment: OK iedriver is my option that is helpful.